# Trouble inserting GLTF file viewer in html (using 3js)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, 3d

I am attempting to insert a GLTF file viewer into an HTML file to be uploaded to a server after local editing (currently have only the HTML and the GLB stored locally, with three.js referenced in script tags.

Under the current setup, the webpage generates the proper full-screen view canvas within the .scene div, but the glb file does not load.

In answer, please include full modified html file with any problems identified. Many thanks in advance.

JS is from StackOverflow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .scene,
        canvas {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="scene"></div>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script>

        //Variables for setup

        let container;
        let camera;
        let renderer;
        let scene;
        let house;
        let mixer;
        const clock = new THREE.Clock();

        function init() {
            container = document.querySelector(".scene");

            //Create scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            const fov = 35;
            const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
            const near = 1;
            const far = 10000;

            //Camera setup
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);

            const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 1);
            scene.add(ambient);

            const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
            light.position.set(50, 50, 100);
            scene.add(light);

            //Renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
            renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.target.set(0, 0.5, 0);
            controls.update();
            controls.enablePan = false;
            controls.enableDamping = true;

            const dracoLoader = new THREE.DRACOLoader();
            dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/draco/gltf/');

            //Load Model
            let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);
            loader.load("./test_file.glb", function (gltf) {
                scene.add(gltf.scene);
                house = gltf.scene.children[0];

                mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(house);
                mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]).play();

                animate();
            });
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            const delta = clock.getDelta();
            mixer.update(delta);

            house.rotation.z += 0.005;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        init();

        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
        }

        window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Issue was with browser CORS policy. Loading in same server as host location resolves reported issues. http or https must be used over file routing.